# Option set rules not comming from Bigcommerce API

Tags: bigcommerce

When I call the rules `https://storeId.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/productId/rules` for a product that has the rules applied from the option set I get a **204 No Content** error.

Is this something temporary? Does anybody have the same issue?

**Actual links:**

https://store-9j2twtgd.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/54/rules
https://store-9j2twtgd.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/54

Comment: Can you clarify that you are replacing productId with an actual product ID number that actually has rules? Please show code with product ID included.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issues with a couple other API requests. What i realized is that due to content negotiation, you have to state the format in which you cant your response.

For example if i want a specific product, i have to do

> https://storeId.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/productId**.json**

In this same regard, i would suggest that you do same with the rules resource. so try out

> https://storeId.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/productId/rules**.json**

Hope this works.